# C# Use lambda expression to get parameter name of method

Tags: c#, lambda

Is it possible to call a lambda expression on a method object in some way so that you can do this..

(x=>x.Property1)

which then should return PropertyInfo?

Right now I have the below:

```
public static class MethodSupport<T>
{

   public static MethodInfo ActionInfo(Expression<Func<T, Action>> expression)
   {
       return MethodInfo<T>(expression);
   }

   public static MethodInfo MethodInfo<T>(LambdaExpression expression)
   {
        UnaryExpression unaryExpression = (UnaryExpression)expression.Body;
        MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression = (MethodCallExpression)unaryExpression.Operand;
        ConstantExpression methodCallObject = (ConstantExpression)methodCallExpression.Object;
        MethodInfo interfaceMethodInfo = (MethodInfo)methodCallObject.Value;

        Type implementedClassType = typeof(T);
        MethodInfo implementedMethodInfo = interfaceMethodInfo.GetImplementingMethod(implementedClassType);
        return implementedMethodInfo;
    }
}
```

Which allows me to return MethodInfo,

```
MethodInfo m = MethodSupport<ImageGalleryController>.ActionInfo(c => c.AttachExisting);
```

but I want something else that will allow me to return PropertyInfo for a given property

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
    public static PropertyInfo GetPropertyInfo<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression)
    {
        return ((MemberExpression)propertyExpression.Body).Member as PropertyInfo;
    }
```